# Include levels of zero on scatter plot in r

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot x and y on a plot with level (0,1,2,3) colorized. X and y plot just fine, but when I try to colorize by level, only levels 1, 2, and 3 show up on the graph. Level 0 is now gone. I also can't get the legend to work for the colors.

```
plot(data$x, data$y, pch=19, col=data$level)
legend ("topleft", levels(data$level), fill=0:3)
```

I'm assuming the error has got to be from my zero level, but what can I do to include the level without going through the data set and changing "0" to something else?

> Error in as.graphicsAnnot(legend) : argument "legend" is missing, with
>   no default

Comment: Make sure that data$level is a factor. Try adding `data$level <- factor(data$level)`

Comment: You might want this for legend: `legend ("topleft", levels(data$level), fill=unique(data$level))`